# How to capture multiple regex matches, from a single line, into the $matches magic variable in Powershell?

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-2.0

Let's say I have the string **"blah blah F12 blah blah F32 blah blah blah"** and I want to match the *F12* and *F32*, how would I go about capturing both to the Powershell magic variable $matches?

If I run the following code in Powershell:

```
$string = "blah blah F12 blah blah F32 blah blah blah"
$string -match "F\d\d"
```

The $matches variable only contains *F12*

I also tried:

```
$string -match "(F\d\d)"
```

This time $matches had two items, but both are *F12*

I would like $matches to contain both *F12* and *F32* for further processing.  I just can't seem to find a way to do it.

All help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: anyone wondering why `-match` returns two _F12_ results in the second attempt, it's because _F12_ is both the result of the _whole_ match expression AND the result of the first match group in the expression (the result of the parentheses...

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can do this using Select-String in PowerShell 2.0 like so:

```
Select-String F\d\d -input $string -AllMatches | Foreach {$_.matches}
```

A while back I had [asked for a `-matchall` operator](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/264229/powershell-needs-a-matchall-operator-that-acts-like-sed-perls-g-option#) on MS Connect and this suggestion was closed as fixed with this comment:

"This is fixed with -allmatches parameter for select-string."

Comment: So how do you reference the captured values, from Select-String -AllMatches?

Comment: @NathanHartley `$string | Select-String "(F\d\d)" -AllMatches  | % matches | % Value`

Comment: Definitely not ideal, since it won't match across new lines.

Comment: @lordcheeto - what if you tried a pattern like: "(?m)(F\d\d)" - the initial (?m) tells regex engine to do multi-line match...

Comment: @user1390375 Doesn't appear to work that way from the `Select-String` command.

Comment: This is great news I didn't know select-string could be used that way thanks!

Comment: (Many years later) [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) now allows you to simplify to: `("blah blah F12 blah blah F32 blah blah blah" | Select-String -AllMatches F\d\d).Matches.Value`. The  suggestion to introduce a `-matchall` operator (as an _expression_-based complement to the _pipeline_-based `-AllMatches`) has made a comeback in [GitHub issue #7867](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7867)

Answer (score 34):

I suggest using this syntax as makes it easier to handle your array of matches:

```powershell
$string = "blah blah F12 blah blah F32 blah blah blah" ;
$matches = ([regex]'F\d\d').Matches($string);
$matches[1].Value; # get matching value for second occurance, F32
```

Comment: I wouldn't use the reserved variable name **$matches**, but an own variable like **$m**. And if capturing groups are present, to show all values of, for example group 1, use: `$m | % {$_.groups[1].value}`

Answer (score 3):

I see 2 scenarios that are handled differently:

1. extracting all matches of a single pattern
2. extracting single match of multiple patterns

#### 1. extract all matches of one pattern: select-string + -allmatches

- e.g. regex: `(?<=jobs).*`
- counter-intuitive but you need to use `Select-String` to handle this like I am to get ids of nomad jobs from the output exemplified below

```
$m = "Watch the deployment in realtime at: https://nomad.foo.net/ui/jobs/20e183af-8243-11eb-a2af-0a58a9feac2a
08:23
Watch the deployment in realtime at: https://nomad.foo.net/ui/jobs/20e130e9-8243-11eb-a2af-0a58a9feac2a"
$r = "(?<=jobs/).*"
$l = Select-String $r -InputObject $m -AllMatches | 
    Foreach {$_.matches.Value}
20e183af-8243-11eb-a2af-0a58a9feac2a
20e130e9-8243-11eb-a2af-0a58a9feac2a
$l[0]
>>> 20e183af-8243-11eb-a2af-0a58a9feac2a
```

#### 2. extract a single/first match of one/multiple patterns: capture groups and $Match[]

```
▶ $s = "Hello World from Mr Pavol"
▶ $r = "(World).*(Pavol)"
▶ $s -match $r
True
▶ $Matches
Name                           Value
----                           -----
2                              Pavol
1                              World
0                              World from Mr Pavol
```

Comment: Easy to learn illustration

Answer (score 0):

```
$String = @'
MemberProgram PackageID="12345678" ProgramName="Install"/
MemberProgram PackageID="87654321" ProgramName="Install"/
MemberProgram PackageID="21436587" ProgramName="Install"/
MemberProgram PackageID="78563412" ProgramName="Install"/
'@
([regex]'(?<=PackageID=\")\d+(?=\")').Matches($String).value
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To improve the quality and avoid getting downvotes, please add additional commentary about how your answer solves the problem. Simply pasting in some source code is not the best way to answer. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I am from China, my English is not very good, I don't know how to write a description. Even if this reply is done with the help of Google Translate.T_T