# Returning a collection of repeated expressions

Tags: regex, powershell

My source is something like:

```
... <a href='...'>...</a> .... <a href='...'>....</a>  ...  <a href='...'>... </a> ...
```

`<a href='(.*?)'>` will give me the first href value?  (For readability I omit \ for those that need escaping but I hope you know what I mean.)  Is there a way to return a collection of all that match the pattern?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Thanks, but I am not really trying to parse general Html text.  My source string is a very well-formatted Html, so I don't have to deal with all the countless possibilities of Html syntax.  My question is more on whether there is a Regex syntax or command to return a collection of all (I don't know how many up front) that matches a given pattern.

Comment: @A.Webb As funny as that link is, it really doesn't provide any meaningful information.  Geezer, have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141851/how-to-capture-multiple-regex-matches-from-a-single-line-into-the-matches-mag)?  I'm not sure if you're looking for more help with what expression to write, or how to use powershell's regex functionality?

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan Yes, my question is the same as the one in the link.  Using SLS achieves what I want to do.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$s = "tralala <a href='A'>A</a> blah <a href='BB'>BB</a>  blih <a href='CCC'>CCC</a>"
$matches = ($s | select-string "\<a.+?href.*?=.*?\'.*?'\>.*?\</a\>" -allmatches).matches
$matches | % { $_.Value }
```