# Complicated Regex with blank lines

Tags: regex, powershell

I am attempting to parse a regex formula in PowerShell and not having any luck. I've created the Regex and have tested it works on RegExr although when I attempt to execute a match query on it it returns no results.

The Regex is looking for any occurrence of a pattern such as below (including the TWO blank line spaces between the Price and the Address.:

```
$9,999,999


26 Fake Street, Fake Island, ABC 9999
```

my regex:`\$[\d]{1},[\d]{3},[\d]{3}\n\n\n\d{1}.*?, ([A-Z])\w+ [[\d]{4}`

My PowerShell code is as Below:

```
$Webcontent = Get-Content 'C:\Utilities\Content.txt' -Raw
[regex]::Match($WebContent,'\$[\d]{1},[\d]{3},[\d]{3}\n\n\n\d{1}.*?, ([A-Z])\w+ [[\d]{4}').Groups.Value | Out-File C:\utilities\NewContent.txt
```

Is it this query possible and also can it return ALL occurrences of this when it finds it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
(?m)s*\$\d{1},\d{3},\d{3}\s*(?:\r\n|\r|\n)+\d+.*?, ([A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)\s+\d{4}
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3Fm)s*%5C%24%5Cd%7B1%7D%2C%5Cd%7B3%7D%2C%5Cd%7B3%7D%5Cs*(%3F%3A%5Cr%5Cn%7C%5Cr%7C%5Cn)%7B2%7D%5Cd%2B.*%3F%2C%20(%5BA-Z%5D%5Ba-zA-Z%5D*)%5Cs%2B%5Cd%7B4%7D&i=%249%2C999%2C999%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A26%20Fake%20Street%2C%20Fake%20Island%2C%20ABC%209999)

All the matches are returned in the global `$matches` variable that is set by the `-match` operator. Please see more on this at [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/powershell.html).

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. Is there a switch or something i might be able to add to make my Regex search the whole document and return all occurrences rather than grabbing the first one and outputting that?

[regex]::Match($WebContent,'(?m)s*\$\d{1},\d{3},\d{3}\s*(?:\r\n|\r|\n)+\d+.*?, ([A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)\s+\d{4}').Groups.Value | Out-File C:\utilities\Amount.txt

Comment: Please check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24835401/powershell-regular-expression-multiple-matches Does that solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

To match newlines you need to match carriage return character as well as new line character in order `\r\n`. So you just need to change `\n\n\n` to `\r\n\r\n\r\n`