# RegEx to find all matches, not just one

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a RegEx expression that lets me find all instances that match a pattern.

PowerShell:

```
> if ("123 234 345 567" -match ".*(\d{3}).*") { $Matches | fl}

Name  : 1
Value : 567

Name  : 0
Value : 123 234 345 567
```

I'd like to also get the other three-digit values as individual matches.

-S

Comment: What needs to be your results with for example "123 4567890"? Would you want something like [here](https://regex101.com/r/hyLImW/1)?

Comment: @JvdV - I only expect specific-length values, so at this point I only need to concern myself with getting multiple matches.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Hm, this seems promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$s = "123 234 345 567"
Select-String '\d{3}' -input $string -AllMatches | % {$_.matches.value}
```

See demo:
[image]

*Notes*:

- With `\d{3}` pattern, you can extract three consecutive digits from any context
- With `-AllMatches`, you can [extract all multiple occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141851/how-to-capture-multiple-regex-matches-from-a-single-line-into-the-matches-mag)/matches
- `% {$_.matches.value}` will get the matched values as strings.

The pattern can also be defined in other ways:

- `(?<!\d)\d{3}(?!\d)` pattern lets you extract three consecutive digits that are not enclosd with other digits
- `(?<!\d\.?)\d{3}(?!\.?\d)` - to match only integer numbers consisting of 3 digits in messed-up contexts
- `(?<!\S)\d{3}(?!\S)` - match three digit chunks in between whitespaces or start/end of string
- `\b\d{3}\b` - match three digit numbers as whole words (not enclosed with letters, digits or underscores).