# PowerShell: How to create Regex for a repeating pattern

Tags: c#, regex, powershell

I have below query I need to extract all the column name changes but if I use

```
$query = ",SELECT A.Title AS Identifier ,A.HOTELNAME AS PROPERTYNAME,A.REGION AS REGION,A.T0STATUS AS STATUS,"

$query -match ",.+ AS (.+),"
```

I only get the last matched pattern,
The result in captured group is Status but I want Identifier,PROPERTYNAME,REGION and STATUS.

So basically my question is how to use regex to find all matches instead of only one.

Code:

```
",SELECT A.Title AS Identifier ,A.HOTELNAME AS PROPERTYNAME,A.REGION AS REGION,A.T0STATUS AS STATUS," -match ",.+ AS (.+),"
$matches
```

Expectation:
Identifier
PROPERTYNAME
REGION
STATUS.

Result:
STATUS

Also there is not much documentation for PowerShell Regex specifically so can you also let me know which flavor of regex PowerShell uses.

Comment: Powershell's regexes are .Net regexes, so there's plenty of [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple matches you will need the [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) cmdlet.
See also: [How to capture multiple regex matches, from a single line, into the $matches magic variable in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3141851/1701026)

With regards to the [regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions),you probably want to use a [Lookahead and Lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
$query |Select-String -AllMatches '(?<=\s+AS\s+)\S+(?=\s*\,)'
```

[image]

```
$Select = $query |Select-String -AllMatches '(?<=\s+AS\s+)\S+(?=\s*\,)'
$Select.Matches.Value

Identifier
PROPERTYNAME
REGION
STATUS
```